# list manipulation with "no indata"

Tags: list, haskell

A further question about List:

```
aaa ::  [[(Char, Float)]] -> Float ->  [[(Char, Float)]]
aaa [[]] a = error "no indata"
aaa [[(a,b)]] c = [[(a, b/c)]] 
aaa ([(a,b)]:tail) c = [(a, b/c)] : (aaa tail c)
```

How to make it work with:

```
aaa [[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)],[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)] ] 4
```

the result:

```
[[('a',0.75),('b',1),('c',1.25)],[('a',0.75),('b',1),('c',1.25)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
> let l = [[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)],[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)] ]
> let aaa list n = map (map (\(c,y) -> (c,(fromIntegral y) / n))) list
> aaa l 4.0
[[('a',0.75),('b',1.0),('c',1.25)],[('a',0.75),('b',1.0),('c',1.25)]]
```

The types in your snippet down match. You try to apply functions defined on float on integers.
You have to pass floats to the functions. That's why i convert the integers with (fromIntegral y) to floats before applying the floating point division "/" on them. The second argument has to be a floating point number too, so use 4.0 instead of 4.

Comment: Thee is no `fromIntegral` needed, since the numbers in the list are already `Float`s.

Comment: `4` has a type of `(Num a) => a` which is to say, any number type. If you use `4` in a way that makes it clear that it means `4.0` the compiler will play along; Haskell is not Ocaml (no offense to any ML/ML-derivative users).

Answer (score 3):

There is a number a ways you can achieve your goal. I think it is instructive to try to implement the recursion explicitly, as you have tried to do. However, I think your code will be more clear, if you split it up into smaller parts. Consider having two functions, with the following signatures:

```
innerTransform :: [(Char, Float)] -> Float -> [(Char, Float)]

aaa :: [[Char, Float]] -> Float -> [[(Char, Float)]]
```

Then you can use `innerTransform` in your implementation of `aaa`.

When you have implemented `aaa` through explicit recursion, you can try to work towards implementing it with functions such as `map`, as described in another answer. As a middle step in that direction, try solving it by mapping `innerTransform` over the outer list. You need to fiddle around a bit with the argument order to innerTransform:

```
innerTransformFlipped :: Float -> [(Char, Float)] -> [(Char, Float)]
```

and then partially apply that function to the float to obtain:

```
mappingFunction :: [(Char, Float)] -> [(Char, Float)]
```

which you can use as an argument to `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension this could be something like :

```
aaa l v = [map (\(a,­b) -> (a,b/v))  x | x <- l]
```